# The network packet is rejected if i make a change in it using libnetfilter_queue

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, netfilter

I am capturing some packets using iptables queue, and analysing them in a libnetfilter_queue module, now i wish to make some changes in the packet, but even if i change a single character, the packet is rejected, perhaps, while checking the checksum! Is there any way to prevent it from being rejected:

```
static int callBack(struct nfq_q_handle *qh, struct nfgenmsg *nfmsg,struct nfq_data *nfa, void *data)
{
 int len=0,id=0;
 char *pktData;
 string pktString;
 struct nfqnl_msg_packet_hdr *pktHeader;
 pktHeader = nfq_get_msg_packet_hdr(nfa);
 if (pktHeader) 
 {
   id = ntohl(pktHeader->packet_id);
 }
 len = nfq_get_payload(nfa, &pktData);
 if(len) 
 {
  int pos;
  pktString.assign(pktData,len);
  pos=pktString.find("oldstring",0);
  if(pos>0)
 {
    pktString.replace(pos,9,"newstring");
    unsigned char* newPktData=(unsigned char*)pktString.c_str();
    len=pktString.size();
    return nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT,len,newPktData);
}
}   
return nfq_set_verdict(qh, id, NF_ACCEPT, 0, NULL);
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with ip checksum or tcp checksum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you change anything you have to update the checksum to prevent rejection, otherwise the packet will be considered to be corrupted...
edit: assuming you are working on IP packets, the above only applies for changes in the IP header, since only the header, not the payload, is 'protected' by the IP checksum.

Comment: Since the code in the question potentially changes the packet length, the checksum does indeed need to be updated.

Comment: Moreover, if it changes the length of a TCP segment, the TCP checksum needs updating, which is easy - fixing the sequence numbers will not be easy. Changing the data in the packets usually means this should be done by writing a proxy, and not done with netfilter.

Comment: An additional thought to that as well...if it's UDP, there's a chance that it too could have a checksum, although checksums are optional with the UDP protocol.

Comment: I am only working with tcp packets, only making change in the payload, actually i am replacing a header value in http header and http header is part of payload at layer 3. Even if the new string is of same length as previous one,keeping length of tcp segment same, the packet is still rejected.

Comment: So, is it possible at all in the above program, to regenerate the new checksum, and replace the previous one with a new one